# GDB in Qt not refreshing values correctly

Tags: qt, gdb

I am trying to use the debugger in a thread but the values of the watched variables dont get updated in them unless i remove the break point, make it run for a while then put break point back.  They also get refreshed if a messageBox appears.  Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a number of reasons.  My best guess is that you're putting break points in decompiled code, where as the compiled code may not occur in that order (as the compiler will move things around).  You should consider setting your compiler to a lower level of optimization.

Comment: That was exactly it, I had a feeling too XD, was used to xCode where the debugger doesn't even stop there anymore which is a bigger indicator.